# performance of entity framework from console application vs web applicatio

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a business component which reads and inserts data from multiple tables.It uses entity framework.
The business component is consumed by MVC web application and a console application.
We are observing huge difference in performance in these 2 cases. Its very slow from Console application.

The component processes a particular case in 10 seconds when invoked from web application while its taking around 100 seconds from Console application. Its happening in production environment
We noticed some difference in test environment, but the difference was not this much(10 times).

Can someone please suggest the reasons that may be causing these and steps we can take to improve performance.

Thanks in advance,
Rohit

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler to see where the bulk of the time is spent? That way you can narrow your search.

Answer (score 1):

imho the reason is that, in the web application, the "context views" are built and loaded once, at the starting of the web app. So the instanciation of a DbContext is very fast.

A contrario, for the console app, the "context views" are rebuild each time the console app is launched. This view building can cost very much, depending on the complexity of the model.

The building of said "context views" can be seen as the initialization of the ORM. This performance issue is particularly true with EF 4.x.

Please read [EF Perfomance considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: In case business component is called 1000 times inside a loop, will "context views" be rebuilt each time. If not then i suppose it is not the problem as it is taking a long time for each call inside a loop.